# Python tzinfo=pytz.utc on existing time

Tags: python, time

I have a variable current_time which is current date time formatted the way I need.   I need to convert the time from completed_date to be in the same format.  I thought the code below would work but it throws error - `replace() takes no keyword arguments`.    I cant seem to figure out the corrent syntax for this for some reason.

```
current_time = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc) # code i use now


completed_date -  2019-12-07T15:17:04+00:00    # print of completed_date variable
completed_date = completed_date.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc) # how I thought I could modify completed_date to look like current time
```

Comment: What type of object is `completed_date`? Looks like a `datetime` but if it isn't that would explain the error.

Comment: that is likely my issue.. completed_date is actually a string.  I am getting the value as part of a json response.

Comment: what does the `+00:00` at the end of the completed_date string represent? Is that supposed to be milliseconds, or some sort of timezone info?

Comment: some sort of timne zone info that is always 00:00 since the report returns utc